# php select query for one results and assign that value for a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get only one record from using my select query and I want to assign that record for some variable how to do it?

```
 $sql = "SELECT ccode FROM customer where ccode='".$ccode."'  ";

 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $cc = isset($Row[0]) ? $Row[0] : '';
    }
}
else {}
    echo $cc;
    if(102310 != $ccode)
        {
          $query = "insert into customer(ccode,name) values('".$ccode."','".$name."')";
          $mysqli->query($query);
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

Comment: There are tons, mega tons of examples and tutorials out there... even here on StackOverflow

Comment: add limit on your query

Comment: SELECT ccode FROM customer where ccode='".$ccode."'  LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

your code will fetch the data, the reason you are not getting an output is that you have mis-typed your variable name  `isset($Row[0]) ? $Row[0] : '';` should be `isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : '';`

You would be better using a fetch column as you only want a single result.

What you really need to do is secure your SQL code from injection, you should never be adding variables directly into a statement.  I'd suggest this as a good starting point: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

-- update --

It's worth noting I'm assuming here that ccode in your database is unique, so you there is only 1 that would equal your value.  Otherwise you will need to add a limit as suggested in the comments, or some more criteria